# Why is ReSharper telling me my expression is always true?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ statement which returns null if the sequence is empty. I assign the result into a nullable `DateTime`. Later on I check if the `DateTime.HasValue` property and ReSharper tells me the expression is always true.

```
DateTime? latestUploadDateInBLSO = Documents.Where(d => d.DocumentLinkId == documentLinkId &&
                                                                  d.UploadedInStage.StageNumber == 6 &&
                                                                  d.DocumentOwnerTeam.TeamId == AuthorUser.Team.TeamId)
                                                                  .Select(d => d.UploadedOnDate)
                                                                  .DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                  .Max();

if (latestUploadDateInBLSO.HasValue) { // <-- Says this is always true
                    Documents.Single(d => d.DocumentLinkId == documentLinkId &&
                                          d.UploadedOnDate == latestUploadDateInBLSO &&
                                          d.UploadedInStage.StageNumber == 6 &&
                                          d.DocumentOwnerTeam.TeamId == AuthorUser.Team.TeamId).IsLatestVersion = true;
                }
```

Since `latestUploadDateInBLSO` can be null, how is that expression always true?

Comment: Is there any code between these two statements?  What is the type of `UploadedOnDate`?

Comment: No, they're sequential

Comment: What is the type of `UploadedOnDate`?

Comment: Before your if statement try a Console.WriteLine command on latestUploadDateInBLSO.value and see if it throws a InvalidOperationException or use a try and catch on .value

Comment: @DStanley `UploadedOnDate` is a non-nullable `DateTime`.

Comment: @Legion in which case your query will always return a non-nullable `DateTime`, hence the result will never be null.

Comment: @CharlesMager I thought an empty sequence would be null regardless of the underlying type of the elements in the sequence. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `UploadedOnDate` isn't nullable, the result will always be a `DateTime` value and never null.  If the list is empty, you'll get `default(DateTime)`, which is `DateTime.MinValue`.

If you want it to return `null`, you'll need to cast your `UploadedOnDate` to `DateTime?`.  You can omit the `DefaultIfEmpty` as per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632(v=vs.110).aspx) `Max` will return `null` for an empty sequence if the type is nullable.

```
DateTime? latestUploadDateInBLSO = Documents
    .Where(d => d.DocumentLinkId == documentLinkId && d.UploadedInStage.StageNumber == 6 && d.DocumentOwnerTeam.TeamId == AuthorUser.Team.TeamId)
    .Select(d => (DateTime?)d.UploadedOnDate)
    .Max();
```

Comment: I was under the impression that `Max()` will throw an exception if handed null. I'm basically trying to get the max value if present and null if the sequence is empty.

Comment: @Legion An empty sequence is not the same as a null or a sequence of nulls. `Max()` cannot handle empty sequences of non-nullable elements. It can handle nulls.

Comment: @GSerg `Max` can handle an empty sequence of a nullable type.  It just returns null.  It only throws if the sequence itself is `null`.  Because of that the `DefaultIfEmpty` is unnecessary here.

Comment: @CharlesMager Didn't know there was a .NET fiddle. Very useful demo. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @juharr this is true. The `DefaultIfEmpty` can be removed in this case.

Comment: @juharr It handles [not all types of empty sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749597/why-is-resharper-telling-me-my-expression-is-always-true#comment61080594_36749744) (try yourself with an empty `List<DateTime>`). In this particular example, when casting to `(DateTime?)`, `DefaultIfEmpty()` is not necessary. Otherwise it is.

Answer (score 3):

If uploadedOnDate is also of DateTime type then it's not NULL. The default value for DateTime is equal to DateTime.MinValue. That is why your nullable will always have a value. If you want to change this you'll explicitly have to say via DefaultIfEmpty and return NULL as default value.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the `DefaultIfEmpty` call combined with a sequence of non-nullable elements (`DateTime`) - you're saying if the collection returned from the `Where` and `Select` is empty, to instead return a collection with a single defaulted `DateTime` within it, so it will never return `null`.

Here's a small sample with the output from LINQPad:

```
List<DateTime> l = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime x = l.DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
x.Dump();

var y = new DateTime();
y.Dump();

l.DefaultIfEmpty().Dump();
```

[image]

Comment: It's not *just* because of the `DefaultIfEmpty` call, it's because of the `DefaultIfEmpty` call on a property that is non-nullable.

Comment: I'm really just trying to avoid a null reference exception with Max if the sequence is empty. If I cast `UploadedOnDate` to `DateTime?` aren't I going to be back where I started?

Comment: @Legion You'll get a `null` value back out if you do that, yes - see [Charles' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36749852/791010).

Comment: @juharr It does if the sequence is of nullable elements. If the sequence is of non-nullable elements and it is empty, `Max()` throws `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: @GSerg You're right.  I wasn't looking at the docs for the correct overload.

Answer (score 1):

DefaultIfEmpty is probably initializing your DateTime object to its default value which is DateTime.MinValue so it's never null and thus HasValue will always return true.